# Most efficient method to store 3D-indexed coordinate data pair in a dynamic, variable-sized 2D data structure?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine, data-structures

Here's an interesting data structure conundrum that perhaps you all can help me with, for context I am writing C#.

### Context/Constraints:

I'm using a library (the new Unity ECS preview package, specifically) that allows me to store data in a very compact/efficient/native fashion for lightning-fast access and manipulation with no garbage collection. For some time it supported storing data in `FixedArray`s:

```
ComponentType.FixedArray<T>(int fixedCapacity) //pseudo-code
```

The API does not allow for any sort of managed data to be stored in these arrays, for performance and safety reasons, which means they must all be linear (no nested arrays or multiple dimensions) and the data elements themselves must be extremely simple (primitives or directly serializable structs, no fancy LinkedLists or references to other data structures). **I cannot use a `HashTable` or `Dictionary` or any other similar data high-level data structure to solve this problem**, I must use the provided data structure!

### Problem:

I am trying to store a basic "Entity" object in the array which has an associated 3D point integer coordinate. I want to access the structure with this coordinate in-hand and retrieve/modify/delete my object from said coordinate. So it was a simple problem of accessing a linear indexed, fixed-width array using 3D coordinates, made possible using a hashing function.

```
//Pseudo-Code, this is not the actual code itself.
//In actuality the Fixed Arrays are associated with Entities in an ECS system.

var myStructure = new ComponentType.FixedArray<Entity>(512);//define array
struct DataPair {
  Entity entity;//the element we're storing
  Vector3 threeDIntegerCoordinate;//from 1x1x1 to 8x8x8
}

//...
int lookupFunction(Vector3 coordinate) {...} //converts 3D coord to 2D linear index

DataPair exampleDataPair = new DataPair(...);
//Data WAS stored like this:
myStructure[lookupFunction(exampleDataPair.threeDIntegerCoordinate)] = exampleDataPair.entity;
//Extremely fast access/lookup time due to using coordinate as index value.
```

Basically, I generated a variable amount (1 to 512, one 8x8x8 cube) Entities and store them by index into the `FixedArray` using a translation function that correlates a linear index value with every single 3D point coordinate. Lookup in a fixed array for a coordinate value was extremely fast, as simple as accessing an index.

**However**!

The package has been updated and they replaced the `FixedArray` with a new `DynamicBuffer` data structure, which is now variable-width. The same constraints apply on what data can be stored, but now, if the cube of Entities is sparse (not entirely full) then it does not need to reserve space for that non-existent Entity reference in the structure. This will drastically cut down on my memory usage considering most cubes of Entities are not entirely full, and I'm storing literally millions of these buffers in memory at a time. The buffer elements are indexed by integer. It is possible to use multiple `DynamicBuffer`s at once (which means we could store the coordinates alongside the elements in two parallel buffers if necessary).

```
//New data structure provided. Variable-width! Also indexed linearly.
var myStructure = new ComponentType.DynamicBuffer<Entity>();
//Is very similar to C# List or ArrayList in Java, for example, contains functions:
myStructure.Add(T element);
myStructure.AddRange(...);
myStructure.Length();
myStructure.resizeUninitialized(int capacity);
myStructure.Clear();
```

***In essence,*** what is the most efficient way to store these variable number of elements in a dynamic, dimensionless data structure (similar to a List) while maintaining 3D coordinate-based indexing, without using complex nested data structures to do so? My system is more performance-bound by the lookup/access time than it is by memory space.

### Possible Solutions:

The naive solution is just to make all the `DynamicBuffer`s length equal to the max number of elements I would ever want to store (512 Entity volume), simulating `FixedArray`s. This would require minimal changes to my codebase, and would allow me to access them by-coordinate using my current translation function, but would not take advantage of the space-saving features of the dynamic data structure. It would look like this:

```
//Naive Solution:
myStructure.resizeUninitialized(512); //resize buffer to 512 elements
//DynamicBuffer is now indexed identically to FixedArray
Entity elementToRetrieve = myStructure[exampleDataPair.threeDIntegerCoordinate];
```

My projected solution is to use two *parallel* `DynamicBuffer`s: one with all the Entities, the other with all the 3D points. Then when I want to find an Entity by coordinate, I lookup the 3D point in the coordinate buffer, and use the index of that element to find the appropriate Entity in the primary buffer.

```
//Possible better solution:
myStructure1 = new ComponentType.DynamicBuffer<Entity>();
myStructure2 = new ComponentType.DynamicBuffer<Vector3>();
//to access an element:
Entity elementToRetrieve = myStructure1[myStructure2.Find(exampleDataPair.threeDIntegerCoordinate)];
//I would have to create this theoretical Find function.
```

Cons of this solution:

- Requires searching which means it would probably also require sorting.
- Sorting would need to be performed every time the structure is significantly modified, which is going to add a LARGE amount of computational overhead.
- Would need to write my own search/sort algorithms on top of an already extremely complicated data structure, which is not designed to be searched/sorted (it is possibly not stored linearly in memory).
- Locality of reference? It is very important that processor caching/speculative execution is preserved for high-performance.

---

How can I find a happy medium between the naive solution and a complex solution involving searching/sorting? Are there any theoretical data structures or algorithms to solve this problem that I'm just completely missing? Basically I need to efficiently use a List like a Map.

Sorry if this is a really long question, but I wanted to get this right, this is my first ever post here on StackExchange. Please be gentle! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's difficult to discern your actual question. You might want to narrow your post and include a [mcve]. I also don't think that searching necessarily requires sorting, depending on your implementation.

Comment: " So it was a simple problem of accessing a 1D indexed, fixed-width array using 3D coordinates, made possible using a hashing function." -> sounds like a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` might be useful for you.

Comment: I think you're looking for a hashtable. @Firewolf34 "I cannot use a Dictionary or Hashtable otherwise I certainly would!" - Why?

Comment: @John sorry if the question was too lengthy to adequately express this but I am forced to use the 2D List-like data structure (called a `DynamicBuffer`). I cannot use a `Dictionary` or `Hashtable` otherwise I certainly would!

Comment: @Terry My mistake, I am updating my question with the appropriate dimension (I meant a linear data structure, 2D)

Comment: @TerryCarmen the data is stored natively, not tracked by the GC, inside a memory chunk associated with Entities in an Entity-Component-System, and is very low-level. No managed data structures like Dictionaries or Hashtables are allowed to be used there, because we cannot use references/pointers to managed data/classes outside that native environment. The advantage is it is blazingly fast and I can create millions of these buffers and iterate over them quickly, the disadvantage is the collections I am storing have to be exceptionally simple.

Comment: @DanWilson I have tried to include some code examples which demonstrate my problem! Hopefully this helps. Sorry for any confusion, it's difficult to express this problem without explaining in-detail the context.

Comment: Just how much space are you trying to save? 512 `Vector3` structures is only about 6 kilobytes of memory. How sparse are your cubes? How large is your `Entity` structure?

Comment: @JimMischel space is at a premium - though the Entity and Vector3 are both comparatively small, and 512 of each of them may only take 6 kilobytes, each one of the 512-length buffers are associated with an Entity themselves and all their connected components.

The Entities (and their associated buffers) are arranged into Blocks. Each Block contains 512 Entities. And then there are 20x20x2 Blocks. Comes out to around a quarter-million or so of these buffers all in all.

Even so I'm more worried about access time and lookup of Entity in the Buffer. I need to perform many in less than 1/90 sec

Comment: You could always implement your own hashtable instead of just storing positions in the second buffer.

Comment: @LeoBartkus That is actually a fantastic solution... I hadn't really considered doing that, but I may end up doing that unless someone posts some really interesting methods on here! I was looking into Knuth's Dancing Links and all sorts of strange things but sometimes the simplest option is the best one! Thanks

Comment: How sparse are the arrays currently? What is the average number of occupied spaces within a 512-item array? What is the distribution? Do you have many that are near full, many that are near empty, and few that are between 25% and 75% full? Are most only about 50% full? Or is density fairly evenly distributed? How often to you add and delete things? Any sparse array implementation is going to trade cycles for space. How much are you willing to increase processing time? 25%? 50%? 100%? Can you show us your `Entity` structure, or at least tell us how big it is?